# Vercel: NextJS app reloads when navigating to ‘/‘

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13, app-router

I have this NextJS [app](https://fer-toasted.vercel.app/) deployed on vercel

I'm using the new `app` directory and make use of the RSC components.

The error presenting in this app is that navigation towards the home route `/` causes the app to reload.

This doesn't happen when navigating from `/` to the other routes or from any other route to any non `/` route. Eg.

- `/` to -> `/posts` or `/projects` NO RELOAD
- `/projects` to `/posts` NO RELOAD
- any navigation hapenning to `/` CAUSES RELOAD

> This issue is present *only* in my Vercel deployment, not locally.

I use the `Link` component from `next/link`.

```
export const NavbarLink = ({
  href,
  // rest of props
  onClick,
}: {
  href: string;
  // rest of types
  onClick?: () => void;
}) => {
  return (
    <Link
      href={href}
      onClick={onClick}
      className={!isMobile && shouldDisplay ? 'ml-6' : 'block'}
    >
      <span
        className={`rounded font-bold md:p-3 font-color-dark--primary ${textColor} ${textSize} ${className} ${!shouldDisplay ? 'hidden' : null}`}
      >
        {children}
      </span>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

and this is `NavbarLink` is used by all of the links in the navbar: `/`, `/posts`, `/projects`.

```
<div className={isMobile ? 'align-center flex justify-center text-center' : ''}>
  <NavbarLink
    href={Routes.home}
    textSize="md:text-4xl text-3xl"
    className={NAV_LINK_HOVER_CLASS}
    shouldDisplay
    isMobile={isMobile}
  >
    FerTostado
  </NavbarLink>
  <NavbarLink
    href={Routes.posts}
    textSize="md:text-xl lg:text-2xl text-lg"
    className={NAV_LINK_HOVER_CLASS}
    shouldDisplay={!isMobile}
  >
    Posts
  </NavbarLink>
  <NavbarLink
    href={Routes.projects}
    textSize="md:text-xl lg:text-2xl text-lg"
    className={NAV_LINK_HOVER_CLASS}
    shouldDisplay={!isMobile}
  >
    Projects
  </NavbarLink>
</div>
```

*things I've tried*

- Using `useRouter.push` instead of `Next` component from `next/link`
- Moving the app directory from `src/app` to `app` (root path)
- Using `Link` component elsewhere than footer and navbar
- Playing with latest next 13 versions. I'm on `13.3.x`
- Played with the `next.config`.

I noticed a `404` in the base route `/` in the network tab, which might something to do?

[image: network tab]

If I follow the trace for that `404` in the console I see this

[image: stack trace]

`next.config.mjs`

```
const config = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.experiments = {
      ...config.experiments,
      topLevelAwait: true,
    };
    return config;
  },
  // images
};
export default config;
```

This is the [repo url](https://github.com/esponges/fer-personal-site) in a case you want to see it all.